# How do I create and plot the frequency class intervals for a numeric column

Tags: r, plot, graph

I have a column(dosage of a drug) of numbers ranging from 0.023 to 122 in a data frame (the numbers don't follow a pattern or anything they are random, and the min and max are 0.023 and 122 ). How do I create intervals and plot the frequency of those intervals as bar graphs in R?
Additionally, how do I plot dosage VS Sex(Male, Female and Unkown) as bar graphs .

I'm new to using R so please help. Thank you!

Comment: You are describing a histogram. You can get a histogram using the R function `hist`. If your data frame is called `df` and your column is called `dosage` then `hist(df$dosage)` should do the trick.

Comment: `library(tidyverse); ggplot(df, aes(x=dosage)) + geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(sex)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `hist()` function is a base R approach, which you can set the intervals with the `breaks` argument.

For instance, if you have the following data frame:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(dosage = runif(1000, min = 0.023, max = 122))
```

You can do a simple histogram where R sets the breaks for you:

```
hist(df$dosage)
```

[image]

Or you can set the breaks yourself:

```
# Randomly set the breaks (just for demonstration purposes)
brks1 <- 20 # even breaks
brks2 <- c(0, 1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 150) # uneven breaks

hist(df$dosage, 
     breaks = brks1)
```

[image]

And if you are unfamiliar with plotting in R, of course you can make it prettier (or in this example, arguably uglier):

```
hist(df$dosage, 
     breaks = brks1,
     xlab = "Dosage",
     col = rep(2:6, each = 5),
     main = "Histogram of Dosage")
```

[image]